# model is damaged when rendering blender 2.7b

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

this is the photo of the model in render view 
[image]

and this the photo of the same model rendered 
[image]

Comment: are you sure that the render option is enabled in the Subsurf modifier of your object?

Comment: a .blend file would be much appreciated...

Comment: yes i enabled the subsurf modifier

Comment: thank you so much for your help